# How can I reference a named cell from another workbook in a formula with a VBA code in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have 2 workbooks. In the first one in cell L2 there is a date and the cell is called "Date".
I have a macro from the first workbook that creates another workbook and uses some information but what I would like to know is how to design the VBA code of the macro so that when the second workbook is opened, and want to have in cell A3 some text which should be connected through concatenate formula in VBA.
I want to have this value: Bank statement from "Date". The words "Bank statement from" have been taken from other cells in the second workbook.

How can I include the named cell "Date" from the first workbook into the VBA formula using concatenate formula within the macro for creating some text in the second workbook in A3?
Simply using "Date" at the end of the formula gives #NAME? error in the cell:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
         "=CONCATENATE(R[5]C[1]," ",R[10]C[2]," ","from", " ",Date)"
```

How to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Qualify it with the book name `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(R[5]C[1],"" "",R[10]C[2],"" from "",'Book1.xlsx'!date)"` (assuming it is a workbook scope name)

Comment: Yes, by adding the name of the first workbook it worked, but it shows it not as a date but 44434 in the cell in the second workbook. Could you please assist ?

Comment: Add a TEXT function `TEXT('Book1.xlsx'!date,""dd/mm/yyyy"")`

Comment: You should only correctly format the cell in discussion. Excel keeps `Date` in that format...

Comment: With text function in cell L2 it worked. Thanks